# Is there any way to calculate milliseconds from DS1307

Tags: rtc

I have a DS1307 and I have done its program and taking out time from it. In my program I have `sec1,sec2` which holds the digits of seconds and same for `min1,min2` & `hr1,hr2`. I am saving all in a variable `TIME`

`sprintf(TIME,"%s%s:%s%s:%s%s",hr2,hr1,min2,min1,sec2,sec1);`

Now `TIME` contains the value of `Hour, Minutes, Seconds`. But I also need the value of `milliseconds`.

Is there any logic which I can use in code or any other way to calculate values for `milliseconds`

**CODE FOR MilliSecond**

```
 //MSECOND is variable to hold millisecond
   int count = 0;
    do
    {
        count++;
        sprintf(MSECOND,"%d",count);
        sprintf(TIME,"%s%s:%s%s:%s%s:%s",hr2,hr1,min2,min1,sec2,sec1,MSECOND);
        putsUART1("Time: ");
        putsUART1(TIME);
        putsUART1(" \n ");
    }while(count<=999);
```

**EDIT**

This question is in reference to my older question: [Where to save DS1307 program to get real time value?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204952/where-to-save-ds1307-program-to-get-real-time-value). I am using `PIC32MX795F512L` MCU. I have not posted the complete code. Its in the link.

Comment: Is that code really everything? It doesn't seem to have anything which will keep consistent time except for the baud rate of UART1. I've responded to the code in my answer. How accurate do you need the milliseconds count to be? What microcontroller are you using?

Comment: @gbulmer I have edited my question with the link which contains code. I thought of using some kind of counters to count from 0-999 and within in a second and synchronizing it with the RTC time.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [DS1307 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf) the SQW/OUT pin can produce a square wave at 1Hz, 4.096kHz, 8.192kHz, 32.768kHz.

The datasheets says:

> CONTROL REGISTER ...
>   Bit 4: Square-Wave Enable (SQWE). This bit, when
>   set to logic 1, enables the oscillator output. The frequency of the
>   square-wave output depends upon the value of the RS0 and RS1 bits.
>   With the square-wave output set to 1Hz, the clock registers update on
>   the falling edge of the square wave. On initial application of power
>   to the device, this bit is typically set to a 0.

So, if you have a spare MCU pin, your system could input that signal. AFAICT, that signal/information is not available via I2C, it is hardware only.

It still depends on how accurate you need milliseconds to be, and how much spare processor you have, you could use one of the higher frequency square-wave signals, and divide down to milliseconds in software.

A simple binary shift (power of two division) would be cheap, but have a few % error. A more accurate division would need a bit more processing.

Edit:
Is this level of accuracy sufficient for your purpose?

Doing something that takes some time, and counting is a potentially fragile way to track time. Your code doesn't show anything which has any kind of time-driven constraint other than the speed of the UART. As the code may be printing different number of characters (e.g. in `putsUART1(TIME);`) then it isn't going to be very accurate. Worse, if there is any other processing to do, the timing loop will drift, potentially unpredictably.

When a system does not have a real-time clock, we normally we use a hardware timer, to maintain reasonably accurate time. However, you have a reasonably accurate clock in the DS1307, and the only hardware needed to track it is an input pin with an interrupt.

You wrote "Its working but don't know why it is missing 1second like after 34thsec it jumps directly to 36th sec."

It appears to miss the 35th second completely. That isn't really working. It is printing some numbers, which look like the right sequence, but that doesn't mean much. It is pretty easy to write a price of code that counts to 999 and prints. That doesn't mean each number took one millisecond to appear.

*If you want more specific help, you need to tell us how accurate the millisecond timer needs to be, and what other processing and peripherals your system is using.*

I've only used PIC32 in very trivial ways, years ago (when they first appeared).

However, the PIC32MX795F512L has a bunch of hardware timers. So these could be programmed to create a reasonably accurate, stable millisecond timer. As well as being timers, they that can also count external events. So one timer could be used to synch with the DS1307.

However, I would just program a timer to be, say, a 0.5 millisecond timer, and occasionally synchronise that with the DS1307. if the PIC32MX795F512L is running from a crystal, it is going to be reasonably accurate. I'd let it run for a few hours, and compare with the DS1307 to understand the amount of drift between the two time sources.

Using the hardware timer will avoid the basic problem of using a 'busy-loop' to get timing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I thought of using a counter and incrementing its value from 0-999 within a second. Its working but don't know why it is missing 1second like after 34thsec it jumps directly to 36th sec. I have edited my question with the code I am using. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code which actually measures time - other than the inherent speed of the UART, which is probably contributing to your missed second.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question some time ago and my current solution (simplest) is the following:

1. Assign SQW pin to a interrupt pin (arduino pin 2 and 3);
2. Set DS1307 to output the square wave at 1Hz;
3. Write on Setup `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt("pin number"),"ISR name",FALLING)` (in my case seconds increase when the sqw signal falls);
4. In the ISR only write `timeref = millis()` (timeref is a global unsigned long);
5. Finally in your code you can do something like this:

`Setup(){
 tref = timeref; //needed in case timeref is updated meanwhile
 elapseref = millis();
 (do some work);
 elapse = millis(); //in my case I want to index time to the previous work
 ReadRTC();
 }
 void ReadRTC(){
   byte tens;
   byte units;
   byte income;
   Wire.beginTransmission(rtc_addr);
   Wire.write(0);
   Wire.endTransmission(false);
   Wire.requestFrom(rtc_addr,7,true); 
   elaspertc = millis();
   for(byte i = 0; i<7; i++){ 
     income = Wire.read();
     tens = income >> 4;
     units = income & 15;
     rtdata[i+2] = tens * 10 + units; // milliseconds will be store on the 1st 2
   }
   ms = (elapse - elapseref) / 2 + elapseref - tref; //the formula can be optimize but it can also lead to overflow. As mention, in my case, I want to index time to (do some work)
   s = elapsertc - tref; //It is needed to correct time case s is equal or greater then 1000 ms (1s)
   if(s>=1000){
     if(ms>=1000){
       ms -= 1000;
     }
     else{
       rtcdata[2] -= 1
     }
   }
   rtcdata[0] = ms >> 8;
   rtcdata[1] = ms & 255;
 }`

I'm working with a redboard (arduino) but in any case it's to give an idea.
Hope it works for you.